# Partial packages in Continuous Delivery

Tags: sharepoint, continuous-integration, package, continuous-delivery

Currently we are running a C# (built on Sharepoint) project and have implemented a series of automated process to help delivery, here are the details.

1. **Continuous Integration**. Typical CI system for frequent compilation and deployment in DEV environment.
2. **Partial Package**. Every week, a list of defects accompanied fixes is identified and corresponding assemblies are fetched from the full package to form a partial package. The partial package is deployed and tested in subsequent environments.

In this *pipeline*, there are two packages going through are being verified. Extra effort is used to build up a new system (web site, scripts, process, etc) for partial packages. However, some factors hinder its improvement.

1. **Build and deploy time is too long**. On developers' machines, every single modification on assemblies triggers around 5 to 10 minute redeployment in IIS. In addition, it takes 15 minutes (or even more) to rebuild the whole solution. (The most painful part of this project)
2. **Geographical difference**. Every final package is delivered to another office, so manual operation is inevitable and package size is preferred to be small.

I will be really grateful to have your opinions to push the Continuous Delivery practices forward. Thanks!

Comment: (I would suggest this is moved to programmers.stackexchange.com) - A couple of clarifying questions - is the compile of the solution taking 15 minutes to compile on developers machines? Or on the build box?

Comment: It takes 15 minutes on both dev machine and build box. And in our 30 member team, a checkin may take more than a half hour to be built.

Comment: Well your first step is to try to reduce the build time. You need to  work out a way to stop everything from re-compiling from scratch - only the stuff that has changed. Maybe you can separate code out into different modules that can be compiled, versioned and so you can link to the binary objects. Maybe better hardware will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the reason that this question has no answers is because its scope is too large.  There are far too many variables that need to be eliminated, but I'll try to help.  I'm not sure of your skill level either so my apologies in advance for the basics, but I think they'll help improve and better focus your question.

**Scope your problem to as narrow as possible**

"Too long" is a very subjective term.  I know of some larger projects that would love to see 15 minute build times.  Given your question there's no way to know if you are experiencing a configuration problem or an infrastructure problem.  An example of a configuration issue would be, are your projects taking full advantage of multiple cores by being built parallel [/m switch](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx)?  An example of an infrastructure issue would be if you're trying to move large amounts of data over a slow line using ineffective or defective hardware.  It sounds like you are seeing the same times across different machines so you may want to focus on configuration.

**Break down your build into "tasks" and each task into the most concise steps possible**

This will do the most to help you tune your configuration and understand what you need to better orchestrate.  If you are building a solution using a CI server you are probably running using a command like msbuild.exe  OurProduct.sln which is the right way to get something up and running fast so there IS some feedback.  But in order to optimize, this solution will need to be broken down into independent projects.  If you find one project that's causing the bulk of your time sink it may indicate other issues or may just be the core project that everything else depends on.  How you handle your build job dependencies is dependent up your CI server and solution.  Doing it this way will create more orchestration on your end, but give faster feedback if that's what's required since you're only building the project that had the change, not the complete solution.

I'm not sure what you mean about the "geographical difference" thing.  Is this a "push" to the office or a "pull" from the offices?  This is a whole other question.  HOW are you getting the files there?  And why would that require a manual step?

Narrow your scope and do multiple questions and you will probably get better (not to mention shorter and more concise) answers.

Best!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# developer, but the principles remain the same.

To speed up your builds, it will be necessary to break your application up in smaller chunks if possible.  If that's not possible, then you've got bigger problems to attack right now.  Remember the principles of API's, components and separation of concerns.  If you're not familiar with these principles, it's definitely worth the time to learn about them.

In terms of deployment - great that you've automated it, but it sounds exactly the same as you are building a big-bang deployment.   Can you think of a way to deploy only deltas to the server(s), are do you deploy a single compressed file?   Break it up if possible.